# Merge Cells in Table

Tags: tables

How can I merge two cells into one cell in a table?

For example, I would like to merge the cell for "456" as follows.

[image: expected table]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\captionof{table}{Test Table}
\label{tab:table_x} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth} { |
  c |
  c |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
}
  \hline
  \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}  \\
  \hline
  abc  & def & ghi \\
  \hline
  123  & 456 & mno \\
  \hline
   jkl  & 456 & 789 \\
  \hline
  xxx  & yyy & zzz \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Current table:

[image: current table]

Comment: Did you have a look at commands like `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`?

Comment: Your current minimal code example isn't compilable. You're missing `\usepackage{tabularx}` and one package that defines `\captionof` (but please note that you don't need `\captionof` inside a `table` environment, `\caption` suffices there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in `tabularx` and with all those rules (I don't like them, they make a table look cluttered, not tidy or legible), I'd suggest using the packages `hhline` (gives better spacing than `\cline`) and `multirow`. I also used `array` and `\extrarowheight` to get better spacing to the horizontal rules (they are too close in default LaTeX).

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Test Table\label{tab:table_x}}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth} { |
  c |
  c |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
}
  \hline
  \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}  \\
  \hline
  abc  & def & ghi \\
  \hline
  123  &     & mno \\
  \hhline{|-|~|-|}
  jkl  & \multirow{-2}{*}[-.5\arrayrulewidth]{456} & 789 \\
  \hline
  xxx  & yyy & zzz \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get exactly the table you show in your image (more or less, that's not exactly the same spacing) don't use `tabularx` but a normal `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Test Table\label{tab:table_x}}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
  \hline
  \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}  \\
  \hline
  abc  & def & ghi \\
  \hline
  123  &     & mno \\
  \hhline{|-|~|-|}
  jkl  & \multirow{-2}{*}[-.5\arrayrulewidth]{456} & 789 \\
  \hline
  xxx  & yyy & zzz \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## What I'd use

Instead of vertical rules (and rules after each line) I'd use the `booktabs` rules. If I need to "merge" cells I'd put them in the first column (if applicable) and simply add `\addlinespace` after each block. Meaningful data (like numeric data) I'd not omit and merge cells, but repeat:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Test Table\label{tab:table_x}}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth} { c c >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X }
  \toprule
  \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}  \\
  \midrule
  abc  & def & ghi \\
       & 456 & mno \\
  \addlinespace
  jkl  & 456 & 789 \\
  \addlinespace
  xxx  & yyy & zzz \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Skillmon, how to make the table with tabularx becomes more concise by deleting the white space area in column "C"? Thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI The column with spec `X` is as wide as necessary to fill the width you specified in the first argument to `tabularx` (so in this case `\columnwidth`), if you want it to be narrower change `\columnwidth` to another value. If you want it just as narrow as necessary, change it to use `l`, `c`, or `r` (left, centre, or right aligned).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really reproducible, since it has some errors (one package is missing). Have a look at my approximation:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{multirow} % <-- added package
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Test Table}
\label{tab:table_x} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth} { |
  c |
  c |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
}
  \hline
  \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}  \\
  \hline
  abc  & def & ghi \\
  \hline
  123  & \multirow{2}{*}{456} & mno \\ % <-- merged cell
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3} % <-- added rule
  jkl  & & 789 \\ % <-- merged cell
  \hline
  xxx  & yyy & zzz \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily using new package tabularray.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Test Table}
  \label{tab:table_x}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec = {QQQ},
      hlines,
      vlines,
      columns={c},
      rows={m},
      cell{3}{2} = {r=2,c=1}{c},
      row{1}={font=\bfseries},
    }
    A   & B   & C   \\
    abc & def & ghi \\
    123 & 456 & mno \\
    jkl & 456 & 789 \\
    xxx & yyy & zzz \\
  \end{tblr}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]